# Angular Frequency of Wave Function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I encountered this while finding separable solutions to Schroedinger's equation: $$i\hbar\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial t}=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\Psi+V\Psi.$$
By writing $\Psi$ as $\psi(x)T(t)$, we have $$\frac{i\hbar\frac{dT}{dt}}{T}=\frac{-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\Psi+V\psi}{\psi},$$ so LHS and RHS are both constant. Denote this constant by $C$, and by solving LHS, $$T(t)=e^{-iCt/\hbar}.$$ Now my notes say that the $C$ here represents the energy since $\frac{C}{\hbar}$ is the angular frequency. But I thought frequency $\omega$ should be the $\omega$ in $e^{i \omega t}$ instead of $e^{-i \omega t}$? I have very limited physics knowledge and would really appreciate it if anyone could explain / give me an idea where to look at. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Better way to go about here is to reorganize that the left-hand side is a Hamiltonian of the system i.e.
$$i\hbar \partial_t \Psi(\vec{r},t)=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\Psi(\vec{r},t)+V\Psi(\vec{r},t)\equiv H\Psi(\vec{r},t)$$
The reason is that in quantum mechanics $-i\hbar \nabla$ acts as a momentum operator. So $H=P^2/2m+V(x)$ gives the above form. Now Using the method of separation of variables, We have
$$\frac{i\hbar \partial_t T(t)}{T(t)}=\frac{H\psi(r)}{\psi(r)}\equiv E$$
The reason for constant to be the energy is now apparent. Since it's an eigenvalue of the Hamiltonian operator and hence eigenvalues are essentially energy.

$$\frac{d T}{T}=-\frac{iE}{\hbar}dt\rightarrow T(t)=\exp\left(-\frac{iEt}{\hbar}\right)$$
Hope this would help.